# Rerversing AND Bitwise

Tags: c, algorithm, cryptography, reverse

Here's the following algorithm:

```
int encryption(int a, int b) {
    short int c, c2;
    uint8_t d;

    c = a ^ b;
    c2 = c;

    d = 0;
    while(c) {
        c &= c - 1;
        d++;
    }

    return d;
}
```

How can I find which variable a and b I should send in that function to decide of the output value of d?

In other words, how can I reverse the algoritm to let's say if I want d=11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
while(c) {
    c &= c - 1;
    d++;
}
```

counts the number of 1-bits in `c`. So for example, if `c = 10110`, d will be 3.

This:

```
c = a ^ b;
```

Does an [exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) between `a` and `b`. This means that all the 1-bits that share the same position in both `a` and `b` will be zeroes, and all the positions that have different values in `a` and `b` will become 1. For example:

```
101110 ^
011010
========
110100
```

So basically, the algorithm finds the number of 1-bits in `a ^ b`. To force it to output a certain value, just make `a = 0` then `b = number with d 1-bits`.

To get a number with `d` 1-bits, consider `b = (2 to the power of d) - 1`.

So if you want `d = 11`, then `a = 0` and `b = (2 to the power of 11) - 1 = 2048 - 1 = 2047`.

To efficiently compute 2 to a certain power programmatically, use this formula:

`2 to the power of k == 1 << k`

So, basically: `encryption(a, b) == d if a = 0 and b = (1 << d) - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`d` is just the number of "1" bits in `c`, see http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan.

Therefore, you just need to find `a` and `b` such that their bitwise-XOR value has exactly 11 bits, e.g. `a = 0` and `b = 2047`.

(This is not encryption. This is a very weak one-way hashing. An encryption have to provide a way to get back the original value (decryption).)

Answer (score -1):

I see it counts SET bits in a XOR b?

Ok, then let's say a==0, b==4095.